# Resuming the fragment after recreating Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

In my app, I have an activity that has Fragment Container, and I am adding a Fragment (FragmentOne) to container when user came to the activity. Once they enter some data in FragmentOne, I am replacing this fragment with FragmentTwo.

When I am on the FragmentTwo, If I take app to the background and come back, it goes to FragmentOne. I want it to back to FragmentTwo. I tried saving instance of current fragment and restoring it. However, backStackEntryCount increases and it causes issues when I press the back button.

What is the best way to achieve this?

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set a flag in your Activity indicating whether the 1st fragment has been completed, you can check this flag to see which fragment to load so the correct one is loaded when you return to the app.  Check this flag where you load the 1st fragment, and if it is raised, load the 2nd fragment instead.

Comment: When I load second fragment, if the user wants to go back to first fragment pressing Back button, they will not land on the first fragment.

Comment: override the on back pressed method and if the second fragment is loaded, replace it with the first and don't add the transaction to the back stack

Comment: I was actually overthinking, I didn't have to do it. I will post my answer soon.